# Increasing MAXIMUM_WAIT_OBJECTS for WaitforMultipleObjects

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi

What is the simplest way to wait for more objects than `MAXIMUM_WAIT_OBJECTS`? 
MSDN lists this:

- Create a thread to wait on `MAXIMUM_WAIT_OBJECTS` handles, then wait on that thread plus the other handles. Use this technique to break the handles into groups of `MAXIMUM_WAIT_OBJECTS`.
- Call `RegisterWaitForSingleObject` to wait on each handle. A wait thread from the thread pool waits on `MAXIMUM_WAIT_OBJECTS` registered objects and assigns a worker thread after the object is signaled or the time-out interval expires.

But neither are them are very clear.  The situation would be waiting for an array of over a thousand handles to threads.

Comment: am i seeing this q over and over again?

Comment: If you detect a cross impedance mismatch between 64 and 1000+ then you're on to something.  The api only really supports sane usage of operating system resources.

Comment: No, @Aaa, you aren't. You simply saw a related question where Jake expressed disbelief that the limit was 64. This one is the follow-up question asking what he can do about it.

Comment: IMHO, If you need to wait for over a thousand of threads, something is seariously wrong with your design. More threads do not mean more speed. I bet the work done by 1000 threads could easily be handled by at most 5-10 threads much more efficiently. Also like @Hans said your are wasting `990 * default stack size` of memory, which may lead to _Out of Memory_.

Comment: @HansPassant: What is "sane" is highly debatable. To give an example, if you create a sub-process, you need to watch 4 handles for std in/out/err plus the process. Which means you cannot launch more than 16 processes due to API limitations. Launching 16 sub-processes may seem like a lot, but it isn't in a time where commodity PCs already have nearly that many hardware threads, tens of gigabytes of memory, and close to 600MiB/s I/O bandwidth. High performance systems surpass these numbers. Launching 16+ processes is something that e.g. an IDE might very well want to do.

Comment: The solution offered by Windows is "use more threads", which admittedly a rather poor solution. What's wrong with allowing a wait operation to wait on 500 or 1000 handles?

Comment: @ali_bahoo: it wastes only address space, which isn't a problem on 64-bit machines. The stacks aren't committed all at once.

Answer (score 7):

If you find yourself waiting on tons of objects you might want to look into IO Completion Ports instead. For large numbers of parallel operations IOCP is much more efficient.

And the name IOCP is misleading, you can easily use IOCP for your own synchronization structures as well.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered this limitation in WaitForMultipleObjects myself and came to the conclusion I had three alternatives:

- OPTION 1. Change the code to **create separate threads to invoke WaitForMultipleObjects** in batches less than MAXIMUM_WAIT_OBJECTS. I decided against this option, because if there are already 64+ threads fighting for the same resource, I wanted to avoid creating yet more threads if possible.
- OPTION 2. **Re-implement the code using a different technique** (IOCP, for example). I decided against this too because the codebase I am working on is tried, tested and stable. Also, I have better things to do!
- OPTION 3. Implement a function that splits the objects into batches less than MAXIMUM_WAIT_OBJECTS, and **call WaitForMultipleObjects repeatedly in the same thread**.

So, having chosen option 3 - here is the code I ended up implementing ...

```
class CtntThread
{
    public: 
        static DWORD WaitForMultipleObjects( DWORD, const HANDLE*, DWORD millisecs );
};

DWORD CtntThread::WaitForMultipleObjects( DWORD count, const HANDLE *pHandles, DWORD millisecs )
{
    DWORD retval = WAIT_TIMEOUT;

    // Check if objects need to be split up. In theory, the maximum is
    // MAXIMUM_WAIT_OBJECTS, but I found this code performs slightly faster
    // if the object are broken down in batches smaller than this.
    if ( count > 25 )
    {
        // loop continuously if infinite timeout specified
        do
        {
            // divide the batch of handles in two halves ...
            DWORD split = count / 2;
            DWORD wait = ( millisecs == INFINITE ? 2000 : millisecs ) / 2;
            int random = rand( );

            // ... and recurse down both branches in pseudo random order
            for ( short branch = 0; branch < 2 && retval == WAIT_TIMEOUT; branch++ )
            {
                if ( random%2 == branch ) 
                {
                    // recurse the lower half
                    retval = CtntThread::WaitForMultipleObjects( split, pHandles, wait );
                }
                else
                {
                    // recurse the upper half
                    retval = CtntThread::WaitForMultipleObjects( count-split, pHandles+split, wait );
                    if ( retval >= WAIT_OBJECT_0 && retval < WAIT_OBJECT_0+split ) retval += split;
                }
            }
        }
        while ( millisecs == INFINITE && retval == WAIT_TIMEOUT );
    }
    else
    {
        // call the native win32 interface
        retval = ::WaitForMultipleObjects( count, pHandles, FALSE, millisecs );
    }

    // done
    return ( retval );
}
```

Comment: Does this actually work? As far as I can see, you could be waiting for several seconds while non-signalled WaitForMultipleObjects() calls time out before you get to the one with the signalled handle. The function is supposed to return immediately any handle is signalled.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look [here](http://www.ksingla.net/2010/01/waitforallobjects-to-wait-on-more-than-maximum_wait_objects-handles/).

> If you need to wait on more than MAXIMUM_WAIT_OBJECTS handles, you can either create a separate thread to wait on MAXIMUM_WAIT_OBJECTS and then do a wait on these threads to finish. Using this method you can create MAXIMUM_WAIT_OBJECTS threads each of those can wait for MAXIMUM_WAIT_OBJECTS object handles.

Comment: If you do use the example code, my suggestion would be to specify a non-default stack space size in CreateThread (say "1", which should round up to a system page in size).  No sense reserving the presumed default 1 MiB of address space per thread when almost none of it will be used.