# EnterCriticalSection crashes with more than 64 threads

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, winapi

Is there a thread limit EnterCriticalSection() can cope with?
The following code works fine with 64 threads, but it crashes when using 65 or more:

```
CRITICAL_SECTION TestCritSection;

unsigned int threadId;

int getThreadId()
{
    int tid = -1;

    EnterCriticalSection(&TestCritSection);

    tid= threadId;
    threadId++;

    LeaveCriticalSection(&TestCritSection);

    return tid;
}

void parallelTest()
{
    int tid = getThreadId();
    cout << "Thread " << tid << " executed" << endl;
}


void
multiThreadTest()
{
    unsigned int numThreads = 64; // fine, but program crashes when numThreads is set to 65 or more
    HANDLE *threads = new HANDLE[numThreads];
    DWORD ThreadID;
    threadId = 1;

    if (!InitializeCriticalSectionAndSpinCount(&TestCritSection, 0x00000400)) return;

    for (int i=0; i<numThreads; ++i)
    {
        threads[i] = CreateThread(NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE) parallelTest, (LPVOID) NULL, 0, &ThreadID);
    }

    WaitForMultipleObjects(numThreads, threads, TRUE, INFINITE);

    DeleteCriticalSection(&TestCritSection);

    for (int i=0; i<numThreads; ++i)
    {
        CloseHandle(threads[i]);
    }

    delete [] threads;
}
```

I guess CRITICAL_SECTION is internally using a semaphore with a max count of 64.
Can I somehow change that?

Comment: The problem is WaitForMultipleObjects, not the critical section.  *Never* ignore an api function return value.

Comment: Reading material:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164040.aspx

Comment: Oh... that did not come to my mind. So the limit is MAXIMUM_WAIT_OBJECTS...

Comment: I also feel obliged to point out that having more threads than virtual cores isn't likely to improve performance (and may hurt performance) - at the end of the day, the system can only do one thing at a time.

Comment: @LarryOsterman: What about performance tests? I'm doing a benchmark test on a MySQL cluster with 5 nodes. The threads are basically all waiting for results from the database. I can easily fire 64 threads on one db machine with increased performance compared to 48. So why not try more?

Comment: If you're app spends all its time blocked on I/O, then yeah, more threads can help - to a limit.  At some point the overhead of managing all the threads overwhelms the benefit of mulitple threads. It might be interesting to investigate the benefits of using async I/O and thus freeing the I/O threads to do more useful work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As nobody wants to answer my question, I will do it myself based on HansPassant's comment to my question.

He pointed out that the problem is `WaitForMultipleObjects()`, which takes a parameter

> nCount [in]
>
> ```
> The number of object handles in the array pointed to by lpHandles.
> ```
>
> The maximum number of object handles is MAXIMUM_WAIT_OBJECTS. This
>   parameter cannot be zero.

(from [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687025%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))

`MAXIMUM_WAIT_OBJECTS` is defined as 64, more informations in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5131807/is-maximum-wait-objects-really-64) thread.

This means: yes, there is a hard-coded limit on the amount of threads, but the restriction is not on `EnterCriticalSection` but on `WaitForMultipleObjects`, which returns an error code I should have checked.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5136775/increasing-maximum-wait-objects-for-waitformultipleobjects) is more information on how to get more than 64 threads working in parallel.